# Possibility to get ViewModel from specific partial view through Javascript Ajax Call?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my doubt.

From my knowledge from ASP.NET MVC, one of the solution to pass ViewModel from View to Controller, is by using BeginForm method.

However, I have a situation such that, my script are seperated in the Javascript file to achieve OOP style Javascript.

For instance,

I have my model...

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I have my partial view with binded with the model

```
@model SampleModel

...
```

Now here's the catch, I have multiple partial view which contains "SampleModel" binded with unique id.

Any possible way to get the correct id and value whenever I do something on any partial view by using Javascript Ajax Call, other than BeginForm method?

Something like....

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',...
});
```

Best If have example. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to receive any property of current binded Model from your `View` to you javascript file you don't need any ajax functions just use any of jQuery selectors.

For example:
in your View

```
@model SampleModel

<div class="yourid">@Model.ID</div>
```

in your script file:

```
var id = $('.yourid').text();
```

You may hide you `div` from users:

```
$('.yourid').hide();
```

If you meant something other in your question, than you should clarify it.

Comment: but if let say i have a complex model, such as custom class (which created by my own) in the model, how could I achieve this approach?